# How do i get a list of users whose roles have first 5 characters are sales

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I need to get a list of users whose role has the first 5 char as 'Sales'
I want to use this on a apex class

My first thought was to use something like this

```
 select id from user where UserRoleId__r like 'Sales%'
```

But this throws an error

```
 No such column 'UserRoleId__r' on entity 'User'.
```

Do i need to query the role object to get all ids and then query the user object using those ids?

is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix the name of the User Role column in your search. Here's is the correct syntax:

`select id from user where userrole.name like 'Sales%'`

You only need to append the `__r` suffix to relationships in queries when the object is custom. For built in objects, you only need the name of the object (no `__r`).

Comment: +1 with just one note, the custom object's related link names are not always `name+__r`, they just have to end in __r and you can customize the prefix. The most obvious place where you must customize is in many-to-many object that links another object to itself. Having two child relationships to the same objects means their names cannot be the same.

Comment: right. i'll adjust the answer to be more specific - should have said 'name of the relationship'.